# Very simple SVG is different between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg

I have a very simple SVG which gets rendered differently between Firefox and Chrome and I have no idea why. Any suggestions? I would not want to use any CSS to specially style things to get them in sync but have a simple stand-alone SVG.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg baseProfile="tiny" height="400.0" version="1.2" width="400.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect fill="#fff" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" height="90.0" rx="5.0" ry="5.0" stroke-width="3" width="350.0" x="0" y="0"/>
  <text font-size="18.0" stroke="#000" text-anchor="start" x="5.0" y="51.0">func: foo_bar_longer</text>
  <text font-size="18.0" stroke="#000" text-anchor="end" x="345.0" y="51.0">class: bar_foo_longer</text>
</svg>
```

Firefox 67 on Linux:

[image]

Chromium 75.0.3770.90:

[image]

Comment: Try explicitly specifying a font rather than having the browser choose.

Answer (score 0):

It seems setting `font_family="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"` on all text elements solved the problem. Browsers do not have the same default font.